# Create multiple temporary tables from seperate date ranges then join for results

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

The mysql query below gets me the results I need. The Trouble im having is creating it in php. Im trying to create the two temp tables below from two sets of date range forms then join the results of the temporary tables to display my final result. The dates in the where clauses are where I will use the form fields. The query below works great in mysql. Wondering if anyone can give me a fresh perspective on how i can approach this. Thanks

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE upsfsttable
SELECT custname,custno,sm,dhlfrt,franchise,date,sublob,resets
FROM upsfreightfstimport
WHERE date > '2014-02-01' and date < '2014-02-28';


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sublobrange
SELECT customername,customerno,lob,franchisename,invoicedate,salesrep,items,retail,cost,margin,lineofbiz
FROM sublob2014
WHERE invoicedate > '2014-04-01' and invoicedate < '2014-04-30';

SELECT upsfsttable.custname,upsfsttable.custno,upsfsttable.date,sublobrange.customername,
sublobrange.customerno,sublobrange.invoicedate,sublobrange.items,sublobrange.retail,sublobrange.cost,sublobrange.margin,sublobrange.lineofbiz
FROM upsfsttable
JOIN sublobrange ON upsfsttable.custno = sublobrange.customerno and upsfsttable.dhlfrt = sublobrange.lineofbiz;

<?php

//make first temptable
$maketemp1 = "
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `upsfsttable` (
`fusfstId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`custname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`custno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`sm` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`dhlfrt` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`franchise` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`sublob` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`resets` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
)
"; 

 mysql_query($maketemp1, $dbhandle) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

//make second temptable
$maketemp2 = "
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `sublobrange` (
`slid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customername` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`customerno` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`lob` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`franchisename` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`invoicedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`salesrep` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`items` decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`cost` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`retail` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`margin` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`lineofbiz` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
)
"; 

mysql_query($maketemp2, $dbhandle) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

//insert into first temptable 
$inserttemp1 = "
INSERT INTO upsfsttable
  (`custname`, `custno`, `sm`, `dhlfrt`, `franchise`,`date`,`sublob`,`resets`)
SELECT `custname`, `custno`, `sm`, `dhlfrt`, `franchise`, `date`, `sublob`, `resets`
FROM `upsfreightfstimport`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28'
";

mysql_query($inserttemp1, $dbhandle) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error()); 

//insert into second temptable
```

$inserttemp2 = "
    INSERT INTO sublobrange
      (`customername`, `customerno`, `lob`, `franchisename`,    `invoicedate`,`salesrep`,`items`,`cost`,`retail`,`margin`)
    SELECT `customername`, `customerno`, `lob`, `franchisename`, `invoicedate`,`salesrep`,`items`,`cost`,`retail`,`margin`
    FROM `sublobrange`
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
  ";

```
mysql_query($inserttemp2, $dbhandle) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());
```

?>

";
    }
    //close the connection
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>

Comment: could you show php version. If this is woking then php version should work too.

Comment: php version 5.3.13
mysql 5.5.24 here are versions im using

Comment: @davidcox 
user2102266 was asking for some code. What have you tried in PHP?

Comment: Yes sorry about being unclear. I tried to ask for not working php code.

Comment: all good. i appreciate your help. i added php to original post

Comment: cant fit all code up. is there another way or place to get it to you.